# Codeigniter pass post information to view along with database result of the post information

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a form that collects the `CustomerName`, `Period` and `UnitOfMeasure`[buom].

I then pass this information to my controller which puts the post data into an array and passes it to the view.

This controller works 100% currently.

```
function new_blank_order_lines() 
  {
 if($this->input->post()){ 
     $data = array(
    'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer'),
    'period' =>$this->input->post('period'),
    'buom' =>$this->input->post('buom')
       );
     $this->session->set_userdata($data);
     $this->Sales_model->get_creditlimit($this->input->post('customer'));
   }
    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$this->session->all_userdata());
    }
    else {
      redirect('/sales/permError');
    }
  }
```

What I want to do is query the customers `credit limit` AND `credit balance` using the customer post value and pass it to my view to use in the next form.

so my model is:

```
function get_creditlimit($customer)
{
    $this->db->select('creditlimit','creditbalance');
    $this->db->from('Customers');
    $this->db->where('Customername',$customer);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
}
```

So in my controller I am calling the model function with:
`$this->Sales_model->get_creditlimit($this->input->post('customer'));`
here I am passing the `customer` post value to the model to fetch the correct credit limit? is this correct?

My question is how do I pass the post information array to the view AND the credit limit information to the view.

Do I need to add the model result to the array and pass a single array? if so how do I do this?

Thanks as always,

Comment: You seem to have one too many `}` in your `new_blank_order_lines()` function. You'll probably want to remove the `}` above this line:  `$this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$this->session->all_userdata());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to the $data array:

```
$data = array(
 'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer'),
 'period' =>$this->input->post('period'),
 'buom' =>$this->input->post('buom'),
 'creditLimit' => $this->Sales_model->get_creditlimit($this->input->post('customer'))
);
```

Comment: Thanks Mudshark, Working perfect except when echo $creditLimit, php output is array... do I need to loop through this?

Comment: If you're always going to receive one single row from your query, I'd do `return $q->row_array();` in your model's method, you can then access the data in your view with `$creditLimit['creditlimit'];`and `$creditLimit['creditbalance'];`.

Comment: Hi Mudshark, did as you advised above, but PHP error is `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`. print_r shows `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [creditlimit] => 300000 ) ) ` no array value for creditbalance. any ideas? thanks

Comment: My Model syntax was incorrect. should be `$this->db->select('creditlimit,currentbalance');`